# How to display multiple variables in a boxplot with R

Tags: r, boxplot

I am not very strong with R, and I am having some issues displaying a boxplot. I am not looking to use additional packages (such as ggplot) - I am trying to do this through just the R core.

I have a data file that has 4 columns. I want to create a single box plot with column 2, 3, and 4. I have tried looking around how to do this, but cannot seem to find a clear answer that doesn't involve ggplot.

So here is my psudo-code:

```
dat<-read.csv("data.csv")
boxplot(x1,x2,x3,data=dat)
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: programming questions are for Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm sorry - I had seen another person ask R questions on here when I was looking up how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
boxplot(dat)
```

or

```
boxplot(dat[,-1])
```

if you don't want the first column.